# trigger after_update() in IPackageController by API call

Tags: python, ckan

I am developing a plug-in for CKAN and I need to trigger a function when a resource is updated or created.

When you modify a resource, it affects the parent dataset by changing the date in last_modified. I want to change the date every time that a resource is added/modified.

When I update a resource, I suppose to update the dataset as well, and I am expecting an after_update() call in IPackageController. This is the behaviour when I use the admin interface, after I edited a resource IPackageController.after_update() is triggered.

Calling the API is a different story, that event is not triggered at all by calling

```
/api/3/action/resource_update
```

```py
import ckan.plugins as plugins

class MyControllerPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):

    plugins.implements(plugins.IPackageController, inherit=True)

    def after_create(self, context, resource):
        print "============== AFTER CREATE"

    def after_update(self, context, resource):
        print "============== AFTER UPDATE"
```

How can I trigger this event by API?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling /api/3/action/resource_update doesn't trigger the IPackageController's after_update function, as it's the resource that's being updated, not the package.

If you call /api/3/action/package_update it should get called?

Or you can use IResourceController's after_update to handle when the resource is updated.

Comment: sorry, I did not explain the problem very well, read again the question please. thanks